# Regex to get value till character '

Tags: c#

I've tried the following regex : `var regex = new Regex("code=.*?'");` to get the value of code=value' till it hits the character '

In the webpage the string looks like this : code=42141241.48643196'

Could someone help me with the regex?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 var regex = new Regex("code=[^']*?'");
```

The `[^']` represents the set of all characters with the exception of `'`.

---

But please: Be aware that [using regular expressions is not the correct way to parse HTML pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1560865).